# NON-Convergent sequence such that every subsequence has a further subsequence that converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Could someone give an example of such a sequence? I am also a little confused about what exactly subsequences are, like if there are any limitations to what elements you can take out of the original sequence or what you can do with it.

Would 1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,..., work?
The subsequences would be 1,1,1,1,1,1,..., and 2,2,2,2,2,..., and subsequences of those would converge.

Comment: That's a very good example, actually. *Any* subsequence (not just the two you listed) must contain an infinity of equal values (either $1$ or $2$ or maybe both), so its subsequence formed by those equal values would be constant, thus convergent.

Comment: I am confused about subsequences though. Couldn't some counter and say a subsequence of 1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,.., is 1,2,1,2,,..., taking every other 1 and every other 2?

Comment: Yes, $1,2,1,2,...$ *is* a legitimate subsequence of the original one. But all you have to prove is that *this* subsequence has a *further subsequence* which converges. To prove that, observe that this subsequence contains an infinity of terms with value $1$. Define the *further subsequence* to be formed by all those terms which equal $1$. This *further subsequence* is constant, thus converges.

Comment: When you have "has" in the question, the question is usually asking "does it exist" rather than "is it always true". So it's true that not every subsequence converges, we know that one does converge, which answers the question.

Comment: Ah okay, missed the has. Could you think of other sequence formatted differently than 1,2,1,2,1,2,.., which has the same properties?

Comment: I suppose any sequence that has at least one value that repeats infinitely many times would work?

Comment: No. Consider for example $1,2,1,3,1,4,1,5,1,6,...$. What *is* true is that any sequence which takes only a *finite* number of values would work.

Comment: So say that sequence you gave, once it hits 1,99,1,100, then goes back to 1,2,1,3,.., would that work since 100 is the limit (finite)?

Comment: Yes, since you could still make the argument that any subsequence must take (at least) one of the values infinitely many times.

Comment: You were asked to produce an example of such sequence, if I understand the original question correctly, which you did. However, not *all* such sequences are of this form. For an example of a sequence which has the given property but has no repeated values, consider for example $1,2,1+\frac{1}{2}, 2+\frac{1}{2}, 1+\frac{1}{3}, 2+\frac{1}{3}, ..$. A sufficient condition is that the set of [limit (or cluster) points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point#Types_of_limit_points) of the sequence is finite (for the previous example the limit set is $\{1,2\}$).

Comment: Yeah I just needed an example but I was curious as to what would define a sequence as having such properties.

Comment: By the [Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem), ***every*** bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence. Since any subsequence of a bounded sequence is bounded, ***any non-convergent bounded sequence*** will be a good example of what you want. In particular, your example $1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,\dots$ is fine.

Comment: Thank you. I learned about that theorem recently and I didn't think of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example works. It is true that a given subsequence may not converge, but any subsequence will contain either infinitely many $1$s or infinitely many $2$s (possibly both). Thus any subsequence must itself have at least one constant subsequence, which of course converges to that constant.